# how to change status from pending to processing in cash on delivery using magento

Tags: magento-1.9

The customer choose Cash on delivery for payment option, the order also get placed but if they review their order the status in shown as pending.How to change status from to pending to processing at the time of customer's order get placed in backend

Comment: which source you are using for your store??

Comment: Sry.. Source means i din,t get u.

Comment: sorry for late reply...

Comment: sourse means opencart or other,which store to develop your site

Comment: magento open cart

Comment: magento or opencart

Comment: i know only opencart

Comment: magento only...

Comment: sorry saranya ,i know only opencart....i think you can change that status in admin panel itself

Comment: you have to particular order than click on **Invoice** button than create invoice after that it will automatically change the status.

Comment: But im getting the error as "There are no printable documents related to selected orders."